# React-Toastify break all styles

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-toastify

I was using react-toastify for a while now, to display warnings. But now when I try to display the warnings, it just open a page with no style and the warning message. Like this:

[image]

Is there any solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your main component (**App.js in create-react-app**):

```js
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';
```